# Group similar functions within objects

Tags: python

I am creating objects that contain the data in a pandas dataframe, and also many functions to import, query, modify and export the data to external files. I am doing this because I want the objects to contain the predefined complex pandas functions that we repeat frecuently.

The list of functions is growing quite a lot so I wanted to be able to group those functions somehow so they are nicelly accessed

Currenly  I have id defined as:

```py
class myclass():
    def __init__(df):
        self.df = df
    def f1(self):
        print("Hello World")
    def f2(self,bar,foo)
        return self.df[["bar","foo"]].somefunction()
# many more functions...
        def f40():
            self.df.rename(...,inplace=True)
```

And I use it like this:

```py
a = myclass(df)
a.f1()
a.f2(bar,foo)
a.f40()
```

I would like however to group it by import functions (i), query functions (q), manipulating functions (m) and output functions (o) so the sintax would look like this

```py
a = myclass()
a.i.f1()
a.o.f2(bar,foo)
a.m.f40()
```

What is the best way forward to do this?

## Edit:

- I have added the self parameter and the dataframe so it is clearer
- @chepner I guess this would work also. I just felt it would be nice to group them so when you start typing `myclass.` then you would only see [i,q,m,o] and then when selecting one of them `myclass.i.` you would only see the input group functions.

Comment: Your methods are all missing a parameter. `def f1(self):...`, `def f2(self, bar, foo): ...`, etc.

Comment: What benefit would having separate namespace objects have over simply prefixing the names? `a.i_f1()`, `a.q_f2(bar, foo)`, `a.o_f40()`, etc.

Comment: I strongly suspect this is a bad use case for classes to begin with. *Certainly* the grouping functions part is. If the functions can exist independently of the objects' data, then methods not attached to a class would be preferred.

Answer (score 3):

One option would be to create a class for each group of functions, and include them in your main class (a technique called [class composition](https://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Object_Oriented_Programming.html#composition)):

```
class InputController:
    """Import functions"""
    ...


class QueryController:
    """Query functions"""
    ...


class ManipulationController:
    """Manipulation functions"""
    ...


class OutputController:
    """Output functions"""
    ...
    def foo(self): print("Hello World")


class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.i = InputController()
        self.q = QueryController()
        self.m = ManipulationController()
        self.o = OutputController()



...
>>> MyClass().o.foo()
Hello World!
```

Comment: This won't work. The instances will not have access to the instance data of `MyClass`. You'd have to pass in the instance data manually (defeating the purpose of relating them to the instance) or duplicate them on `MyClass` to pass in the instance data (defeating the purpose of separating them).